# Infinite series inequality.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have some trouble with the following problem:

Show that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+1)\sqrt[p]{n}}<p$$ is true for every natural number $p$.

I tried using induction but I can't finish the proof. Or there is a simpler way to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: where did you get stuck with induction?

Comment: @Dando18 I don't know how to write an inequality between this series and the one where p=p+1.

Comment: We have equality for $p = 1$. And one may note that $$p = \int_0^1 t^{\frac{1}{p}-1}\,dt.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1.** Let $a = \sqrt[p]{n}$ and $b = \sqrt[p]{n+1}$. If $p > 1$ is an integer, then

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{(n+1)\sqrt[p]{n}}
&= \frac{p}{ab \cdot pb^{p-1}} \\
&< \frac{p}{ab \cdot (b^{p-1} + ab^{p-2} + \cdots + a^{p-1})} \\
&= p \cdot \frac{b - a}{ab (b^p - a^p)} \\
&= p \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt[p]{n}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt[p]{n+1}} \right).
\end{align*}

Summing over $n = 1, 2, \cdots$ gives the desired inequality.

---

**Solution 2.** Let $p \geq 1$ be real and write

$$ p \left( \frac{1}{n^{1/p}} - \frac{1}{(n+1)^{1/p}} \right)
= \frac{p}{(n+1)n^{1/p}} \left[ (n+1) - n^{\frac{1}{p}}(n+1)^{1-\frac{1}{p}} \right]. $$

By the Jensen's inequality (or by the AM-GM inequality if $p$ is integer), we have

$$n^{\frac{1}{p}}(n+1)^{1-\frac{1}{p}} \leq \frac{1}{p}\cdot n + \left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\cdot(n+1) = n+1 - \frac{1}{p} $$

with the equality exactly when $p = 1$. So it follows that

$$ p \left( \frac{1}{n^{1/p}} - \frac{1}{(n+1)^{1/p}} \right) \geq \frac{1}{(n+1)n^{1/p}} $$

with equality if and only if $p = 1$. Summing over $n = 1, 2, \cdots $ gives the desired inequality.