Proving the inequality $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+1)\sqrt{n}} \lt 2$
The question goes out as follows:
Prove the inequality $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+1)\sqrt{n}} \lt 2$$
The solution is as follows:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+1)\sqrt{n}} &= 1 + \sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1}}{n} \\
&\lt 1 + \sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1}}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n-1}} \\
&= 1 + \sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} = 2.
\end{align*}
But here's the thing, I didn't understand the first step itself. The other steps were fine, but I didn't get the first step. Can anyone help me out here? Thanks in advance!
P.S. It's worth mentioning that $\frac{1}{(n+1)\sqrt{n}} = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}-\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+1}$

This is a special case of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2378857/42969.

$$\begin{align} &\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)\sqrt{n}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}-\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+1})\\ &= \frac{\sqrt{1}}{1} - \frac{\sqrt{1}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} \cdots  \\ & = \frac{\sqrt{1}}{1} - (\frac{\sqrt{1}}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})-(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3})-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} \cdots\end{align}$$
Now the pattern should be clear.

But it's not clear as how this is less than $2$.

@WangYeFei The solution is given in the post, the only thing to verify is the first step. As you can see it is mentioned in the post that "the other steps are fine".

@KhaledAlekasir Got it, thanks!

Another way to see it: it suffices to show that
$$\frac{1}{(n+1)\sqrt{n}} < 2\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\bigg)$$
Once you have this you can add the telescoping sum to get a bound of $2$. Multiplying through by $\sqrt{n(n+1)}$ the above is equivalent to
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} < 2(\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n})$$
Using that $\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} = {\displaystyle \frac{1} {\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}}}$ the above is equivalent to
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} < \frac{2}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}}$$
This last equation is true since $\sqrt{n} < \sqrt{n+1}$ and thus the right hand side will shrink if $\sqrt{n}$ is replaced by $\sqrt{n+1}$, producing the left hand side.

Thank you very much!

Consider the following computation:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{(n+1)\sqrt{n}} &= \sum_{n=1}^N \biggl( \frac{\sqrt n}n - \frac{\sqrt n}{n+1} \biggr) \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\sqrt n}n - \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\sqrt n}{n+1} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\sqrt n}n - \sum_{n=2}^{N+1} \frac{\sqrt{n-1}}{n} \\
&= \biggl( 1 + \sum_{n=2}^N \frac{\sqrt n}n \biggr) - \biggl( \sum_{n=2}^N \frac{\sqrt{n-1}}{n} + \frac{\sqrt{N}}{N+1} \biggr) \\
&= 1 + \sum_{n=2}^N \biggl( \frac{\sqrt n}n - \frac{\sqrt{n-1}}{n} \biggr) - \frac{\sqrt{N}}{N+1}.
\end{align*}
Taking the limits of both sides as $N\to\infty$ yields
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)\sqrt{n}} = 1 + \sum_{n=2}^\infty \biggl( \frac{\sqrt n}n - \frac{\sqrt{n-1}}{n} \biggr) - 0,
$$
which justifies the first step.

You're right, good catch everyone. Modified.

Thank you very much!
